# Vue js dynamic update set/unset class

Tags: vue.js, focus

I have few inputs with submit button. Have some validation logic that adds 'has-error' class to input. How can i unset this class on focus?

**Template:**

```
<div class="input-styled badge-icon" :class="{ 'has-error': errors.email}">
    <input type="text" @focus="delete errors.email" v-model="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
</div>
<button @click="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JS**

```
data() {
    return {
        errors: {},
        email: ''
    }
},

methods: {
    submit(){
        this.errors = {};
        if(!this.email){
            this.errors.email = 'Something';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying delete error property, trying @focus='errors.email="" ', but class 'has-error' disappears only when i'm typing something on inputs. @focus event works and i think that i should call some function that will update my DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to move operations on component's data to functions. You can achieve desired validation reset, by creating a `resetValidation` function and binding it to focus event on input field.

Method itself should reset `errors` field to falsy values. Example below assumes, there are multiple input fields in the form. Each field should call `resetVlidation` method with corresponding error field name. If no field is provided, we can reset validation as whole:

```
resetValidation (field) {
  if (field) {
    this.errors = {
      ...this.errors,
      [field]: ''
    }
  } else {
    this.errors = {}
  }
```

Please, check the working example below:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vm01z5m947)

Comment: I can't reset a whole errors object on just focus one input, i have 20 inputs and i want to reset exactly 'current' input

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from issue description. I've updated codesandbox link and answer to match your request.